# Mapping in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 DataFrames:

```
df1 
    names            1       2       3       4       5
0   abcdefg       43.9  32.875  34.025  51.625   74.025
1   efgh          42.775     23.975 40.675  41.375        2.695
2   ijk            2.29 23.6530000  68.175  68.875  2.29
3   lmn            23.504   26.503  36.425  36.65   10.742
4   opq             6.98    7.515   6.98    7.515   

df 2
         Numbers
54174    42.775
54175    43.900000
54176    35.550000
54177    35.550000
54178    43.900000
```

Is there anyway to check if the df2.Numbers is at all in df1, and if so extract the relevant df1.names into a separate dataframe?
Expected output:

```
         Numbers     Revised
54174    42.775       efgh
54175    43.900000    abcdefg
54176    35.550000    NA
54177    35.550000    NA
54178    43.900000    abcdefg
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is the expected output?

Comment: Be careful when comparing `float` values, there might be small non-visible representation errors.

Comment: Hi, updated now @yatu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, using `set_index` and `stack` then merge onto `df2`.

You should also take Quang's advice into consideration.

```
s = df1.set_index('names').stack().reset_index(0).rename({0 : 'Numbers'},axis=1)


df3 = pd.merge(df2,s,on='Numbers',how='left')

print(df3)

     idx  Numbers    names
0  54174   42.775     efgh
1  54175   43.900  abcdefg
2  54176   35.550      NaN
3  54177   35.550      NaN
4  54178   43.900  abcdefg
```

Comment: No problem @Nic don't forget to accept this answer if it answered your question

Comment: Hi, I would if I could but I do not have enough reputation points yet.  If I wanted to append df3.names to another dataframe, how would I do that?

Comment: @Nic that's an upvote, green tick is below that have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) For your question you can use either `.join` or `pd.concat` depends on your use-case I'd ask a new question or see if there is something that matches your use case